# Count findings of string in folders

Tags: grep

I have a folder with `.tex` files and want to find how many `TODO`s there are in all files. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
grep -r "TODO" chapters/*.tex | wc -l
```

This gives me each line that has (at least) one `TODO`. How do I need to change it such that it does not count the lines but really the occurences, in order to cover the case that one line can contain multiple `TODO`s?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` flag:

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

For example `grep -ro "TODO" chapters/*.tex | wc -l`